# C# Race-Condition and Null-Conditional Operator in Object/Method-Chaining Method Calls

Tags: c#, race-condition, method-chaining, null-conditional-operator

*I know this is asked in various situations, but I didn't find this exact question, or satisfying answers, sorry, if I wasn't enough cautious.*

**Symptoms:**

When having nested objects, Like `Class A` having reference to `Class B` having reference to `Class C` having a function like `MyCall()` and I have to call this function, but I can not be sure any of the classes became disposed or nulled, I usually use the [Null-Conditional Operaton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) as a simplified call:

```
myClassC?.myClassB?.myClassC?.MyCall();
```

This usually works just fine, but in very rare cases running stops with `NullReferenceException`.

This happens when for example `ClientSession?.WebsocketConnection?.SocketConnection?.Disconnect()` is called somewhere in the code, to disconnect the client socket, but while this call is running asynchronously, the Client remotely disconnects, and for example `SocketConnection` class gets disposed.

So a race-condition causes a situation, when null-checking actually can get to the function call at the end, but when execution happens any object in the chain becomes null, so the method can not be executed, therefore causing `NullReferenceException`.

**Question:**

What should be the proper way, to avoid this situation? Without using `try/catch`, because this is a performance sensitive application, and regarding my benchmarks, catching an error like this is kind of expensive.

Is there any proper way to cancel the execution if any object get nulled?

Thank You for the help.

Comment: `myClassC?.MyCall()` compiles to something like `var tmp = myClassC; if (tmp != null) tmp.MyCall()`; same with property access. If you're getting an NRE, it's likely throw from within one of those property accesses / method calls: the null-conditional operator itself won't throw one. What's the exact stack trace of the NRE?

Comment: Maybe `ClientSession?.WebsocketConnection?.SocketConnection?.Disconnect() ?? AnyThing()`

Comment: @canton7 - I know it is a shorthand for (if != null), I was just hoping it is checking a bit smarter. I can not show now stack trace since this is a race-conditional problem, it happens very rarely so I'm not having it at hand, but when code stops running usually the first object is null, not the last. Same happens when one of the middle is null. I try reproduce it, but can not promise, so don't await.

Comment: @SalahAkbari - That might be useful only (i guess) if the method at the end returns null, not if any other objects gets null while calling the method. This is a race-conditional problem, not a null object problem. The method does not need to return any value, it must execute code, it might be simply a void function.

Comment: @beatcoder My point was that it null-checks a *copy* (which I called `tmp`). There's no chance for something to become null between being checked for null, and having a method called / property accessed on it (unless you're dealing with nullable value types which are fields, interestingly).

Comment: @beatcoder Even if it's raised because of a race condition, a NullReferenceException is still an exception, and will still have a stack trace.

Comment: @canton7 - I'm not sure a function counts as a field in a class, and therefore may be null (if it is not just a delegate variable), if (any of) its parent object gets disposed. The copy of the checked value is just a reference to another object, so it may be null any time, if another thread makes it null. Reference wasn't null in the moment of checking, but later it is.

Comment: @canton7 - I try reproduce with loops and check the stack trace, thats all I can do now, or just wait it to happen.

Comment: @beatcoder: "The copy of the checked value is just a reference to another object, so it may be null any time, if another thread makes it null". That's wrong, another thread may set `other` reference to null, true, but local copy reference woudn't change because of that. Remember yourself about `ref` keyword, if you fail to understand - why. So, NRE may arise only inside a `MyCall`, `?.` operation is thread safe in some terms. For sure, to the moment of execution of `MyCall`, any object may be actually null.

Comment: @lilo0 - I'm not really sure, because I need to test this, but by the moment of checking myClassC? isn't null, it isn't null, so runtime goes executing MyCall() function, but meanwhile another thread calls dispose on myClassC, so actually the temp var actually is not null, but where its pointer is pointing at is the class object, which is null. Without the stacktrace I can not detemine exactly what opeation throws the exception, but I'm pretty sure the last object - which has the function - was shown null in the debugger. It didn't happen since I've posted. When I'll run in it again I'll tell.

Comment: Well, it happened again, there is no point to copy the stacktrace, since it didn't have any useful information. The last entry was the method at the end of the chain, and I couldn't even check now which object was null (hovering the cursor in VS2019 with dotnet core 3 didn't show anything in the tooltip - btw why? dotnet core debugging is just useless, stacktrace usually shows the call tree, but nothing useful, stopping to debug many times results in unviewable variable, doesn't matter which thread I'm looking at..)